# Loose front brake calipers

Tags: ford, brakes, ranger

2010 Ford Ranger XL front calipers are loose.I had new pins,boots and clips put in and they are still loose.Could this be because of worn rotors or worn pads? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean by loose, that once correctly assembled and installed in the right position, and without activating them by means of pressing the brake pedal, you can move the calipers with your hands or by using a screwdriver as lever and you feel some level of play: it could be that the "ears" that are used to secure them against the knuckle, being by bolts or sliding pins, got worn out.

Worn rotors/pads do not commonly make calipers loose, however they can severely damage the aforementioned elements, specially the caliper ears in those with sliding pins...too much rattling can make things loose, damage holes, etc.

Solution? If the caliper holes are damaged, change the caliper, if the problem are the sliding pins, change them but be double sure the caliper ears are ok and that the sliding pins doesn't have any play in it. They, obviously, need to slide in/out by thumb pressure and with some light oil applied.

Ah...now I remember: some sliding pins systems can have one or two rubber rings wrapped around them, commonly in the middle. If they are damaged, they will make the caliper feel loose. Changing them would suffice.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming here that the pins, pads etc are the correct type and are fitted correctly.  The caliper body can move slightly on its slide pins, this loose feeling is exaggerated as well after fitting new pads etc as the calipers piston/s have not yet pushed together again onto the rear of the pads. Once the brakes have been pumped up a few times you should notice the caliper body is a little more secure,  although it will still move slightly as it floats on it's slide pins.